# Where can I see which ubuntu release ships the fixed version of a program affected by a bug?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting

This bug is marked "fixed released":

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1290847

Where can I see which Ubuntu release ships the fixed version?

PS: I would like to avoid reading the long floating text. Is there no database entry for this?

**Update:** I am wearing end user glasses. I don't care about the package version with the fix. I care about the ubuntu release with the fix.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1290847/comments/68

Comment: Good question. For my knowledge, there is not a simple way to find exactly in which version(s) of the package the fix lands.

Comment: @muru I imagine this question is not specific about **that** bug. The idea is --- suppose it has passed six month now. I want to check if my package (say `whatever-3.4.6-ubuntu6.3+build3`, for example) has the fix in it or not... this is what I think the OP is asking - true? If yes, think editing the question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: @Rmano if that's the case, I'd say the only way is: read the changelogs.

Comment: @muru probably yes. And comfy that the changelogs are well kept --- not happening in all the packages I saw, unfortunately ;-|

Comment: @guettli fixes can be in the initial release, or fixed afterward in the same release with an update. You can easily check which package version is in which release at for example http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ --- the main info would be which version of the package has the fix.

Comment: @Rmano I wear end user glasses. I have not changed the default ubuntu settings for updates. This means I have all updates installed. If I set on my developer glasses it is very easy to check which package version is in which ubuntu version. Are you confused now? I do software development with linux since twinty years. I know how to help myself. But ... Why is the obviously interesting information missing? Dear detail lovers: Put on newcomer glasses!

Comment: Yes, I understand. So I think that my first comment stands, with `:s/version(s) of the package/release(s)/` ;-)

Comment: @muru I think important information like this must be stored in the structured database of launchpad.

Comment: @guettli it depends on what "important" is. *Important* stuff like CVE fixes are tracked.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are wearing a pair of end user glasses **;)** – here is an answer including images…

Your [mentioned bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1290847) has a fix and the fix is released. However, it is not yet clear in which Ubuntu release it will be included.

[image]

And the [comment #43](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1290847/comments/43) is also interesting (Thanks [@muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru)).

> > Why is this marked as "Fix Released? This is still broken.
>
> Fix released means fixed in the development series, not necessarily
>   in released versions of Ubuntu.

---

An other example is bug [1264554](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1264554) in the same package. As you can see in the screenshot, the fix for the bug was released for Trusty.

[image]

---

*What does that tell us?*

As long as you can't see this nice icon with the name of the Ubuntu release

[image]

the bug isn't fixed.

Comment: Don't forget the LP bug itself - messages on the LP bug itself indicate when things're fixed (except for things fixed by merges from other OSes)

Comment: Relevant: [Comment #43](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1290847/comments/43) in the first bug.

Comment: I think there needs to be a new state: "Fixed in dev". This way you can distinguish between "Fix Released" (for example in Trusty) and the state  which is label like this in the comment: "Fixed released means fixed in the development series, not necessarily in released versions of Ubuntu."

Comment: @guettli that's called fix committed but it would not get set for the package bug - only in the project upstream (I.e. the python project's bug trackers)

Comment: "As long as you can't see this nice icon with the name of the Ubuntu release...the bug isn't fixed": this isn't necessarily always true. If a bug is fixed in the development release of Ubuntu, then every subsequent Ubuntu release will normally have the bug fixed, but will generally not be explicitly named in the bug status.

Answer (score 0):

I took this question to be, how do I find, which releases contain a certain version of a package.

You can find a lot of information by looking at the ubuntu packages site.  I just searched for the package 'python3' in all versions of ubuntu:-
http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python3&searchon=names

It came up with this:-
Package python3

- precise (12.04LTS) (python): interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version) 
  3.2.3-0ubuntu1: all
- precise-updates (python): interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version) 
  3.2.3-0ubuntu1.2: amd64 i386
- trusty (14.04LTS) (python): interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version) 
  3.4.0-0ubuntu2: amd64 i386
- utopic (python): interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version) 
  3.4.2-1: amd64 i386
- vivid (python): interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version) 
  3.4.3-1: amd64 i386
- wily (python): interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version) 
  3.4.3-4ubuntu1: amd64 i386

Hence I think Python version 3.4 is in trusty, utopic, vivid and wily

It would be helpful, if who-ever on launchpad marked something as fixed, identified which version of python contains a particular fix, but as the discussion on launchpad said, that's not straight forward (and I'd argue, it's not an ubuntu specific issue either).

Comment: Sorry, and where is the answer? :)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  you look in the bug, history for the version of python containing your fix, then you search the packages list for the major version of your package, then look at the list.  I can't be much clearer than that.

Comment: If the launchpad history doesn't tell you the version of something containing your fix, you'd need to ask the python development team, and check up on their bug tracking system I guess.  As this question is on an ubuntu forum, I took it to be a question regarding the ubuntu part of the question, and answered the question as put, rather than as intended